# Python how to set number of spaces per tab key in interactive shell

Tags: python, shell

How does one set number of spaces per tab key in interactive shell - I can't seem to find it, in the docs.

Comment: @qqvc - He means the interactive interpreter, not IDLE.  And I don't think that is possible, user3467349.  The interactive interpreter is very simple and doesn't have many configuration options.  You'd be better off using an IDE that hosts Python like IDLE.

Comment: Why is this being downvoted by people that don't know the difference between interactive shell and IDLE? (also I can't stand idle as an IDE or as an interactive shell)

Comment: You don't *have* to use IDLE.  I was just saying the REPL is too simple to support this functionality.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.  You're entering a literal tab character.  Python isn't responsible for how it displays; your terminal is.

It's possible your terminal has a way to configure this, but I'd advise against it, as other programs are very likely to assume the de facto standard tabstop of 8.

Comment: All editors that run in the terminal allow replacing tabs with spaces / altering number of spaces, - whether python interactive shell allows it or not - it certainly is conceivable that it should do so, and it's not a terminal problem.

Comment: it _could_, but it doesn't.  the python repl is extremely barebones.